# Can I define assumptions in lean?

Tags: lean

I'm just starting out with Lean. Can I define define the assumptions of a theorem?

For example, proving that for any integer pair `min` and `max`, every number `x` such that `min <= x <= max`, that `min^2 <= x^2 <= max^2`. I can define for all integers, but how can I only solve this when the values of `min` and `max` meet a constraint (`min <= max`)?

Comment: By the way there is a new proof assistants stack exchange https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would state this theorem like this

```hs
example (min max x : ℤ) (hxm : x ≤ max) (hmx : min ≤ x) : min^2 ≤ x^2 ∧ x^2 ≤ max^2
```

The fact that `min ≤ max` follows from the other two assumptions, so you needn't include it as an assumption.

Comment: Note that the example as it stands isn't true because e.g. if x=0 but min is negative its square is positive.